# Interaction in logit

Tags: regression, logistic, least-squares, interaction

I am estimating a model where interaction terms play a role, and I am wondering which specification I should use, and how to interpret the results.

More specifically, I regress a binary variable, say Y, on a bunch of covariates, some continuous, some binary. Interaction between some binary covariates play a role.

I am mostly interested in the effect of one covariate, let's call it X, which I interact with other covariates, say Z:

$$Y = \beta_X \cdot X + \beta_Z \cdot Z + \beta_{XZ} X \cdot Z + u$$

With OLS, $\beta_X$ is not significant(ly different from 0), but $\beta_{XZ}$ is.
With logit, it is the contrary.

I guess I should use logit, but I am not sure how to interpret $\beta_{XZ}$, given what I read on the topic: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3447245/ and https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/seminars/deciphering-interactions-in-logistic-regression/.

Also, how to interpret the results? Has $X$ an effect by itself (as logit tends to show) or only when interacted (as seen with OLS)?

Comment: Some similar Qs: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111383/binary-logistic-regression-with-interaction-terms, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/identification-of-confounder-in-a-logistic-regression-model-example-in-applied, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95372/interaction-terms-in-logistic-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401171/interpreting-interactions-in-logistic-regression-in-r, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246873/ols-vs-logistic-regression-does-the-interpretation-of-interaction-differs/247035#247035